# Center USA cities on iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, gis, google-maps-sdk-ios

Based on a city name, like San Diego, we need to center map on that city in the iOS application.

We thought on using top left coordinates and botton right coordinates for each city, however this cannot be automated.
Another solution was taking the center of the city based on data from Google Maps, however we need to define a zoom for each
city that must depend on it's boundaries.

What approaches can you think? How can we define the zoom for the second approach?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure Google offers some geo data on the bounds of cities - their maps certainly show it.  You could also take a good guess based on population of that city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `viewport` JSON output of the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding)? It contains the northeast and southwest coordinates that you can pass into [fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_update#aa5b05606808272f9054c54af6830df3e).